# Numpy Create Array Based on Index Values (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In Numpy, I can create a 2D array like this:

`arr = np.array([[0 for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)], dtype=np.uint8)`

But I can also create the same array like this, which is much faster because it avoids the Python list comprehension:

`arr = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)`

However, suppose instead I want the contents of the array to have values which depend on the x and y values.  For example, I could do something like this (where `f(x,y)` is some function I define elsewhere):

`arr = np.array([[f(x, y) for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)], dtype=np.uint8)`

but this is very slow and has the same problem I mentioned earlier.  Is there a way to create such an array with performance similar to numpy.zeros, perhaps something like:

`arr = np.values(f(x,y), (height, width), dtype=np.uint8)`

?

Comment: Does `f(x,y)` only work with scalar values of `x` and `y`?  Or will it work with arrays?  If it only works with scalar values, then it has to be called once for each element of `arr`, right?  There's no magic that will turn your function into a fast compiled one that uses arrays (unless you want to get into `numba` or `cython`).

Comment: Yes, `x` and `y` are scalars.